# How to return a layout that I opened to the previous

Tags: android, android-layout

That is my case. I opened a layout inside one previously layout, using setContentView. I am using fragment layout too.
When i put finish(), all my activity and my app closed.
I want just close this layout. How can i do that?

if you see, i open setContentView to show my Video. And when complete I want just go back to previous layout, that shows others buttons

I already try put: getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.fragment_um_layout);
But just layout appears, i can't click on my buttons anymore...

Sorry for my english.

Here is part of my code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_um_layout,container,false);


    nao=(ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.nao);
    nao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.layout_videos);

            VideoView video_view = (VideoView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.videoView2);


            Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.nao);

            media_control = new MediaController(getActivity());
            video_view.setMediaController(media_control);

            video_view.setVideoURI(uri);
            video_view.requestFocus();
            video_view.start();

            video_view.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                    finish();

                }
            });

        }
    }                       );
```

Thanks anyway

Comment: Is the layout of the fragment embedded in the layout of the activity?
Does the layout of which comes above also corresponds to the layout of a fragment? Could you show these xml?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should not be using a `Fragment` at all. A fragment should not be re-setting it's `Activity`'s content view.

Instead of launching a `Fragment`, your current `Activity` (let's call it `A`) should use `startActivity()` to start a new `Activity` (call it `B`), and `B`'s `onCreate()` should set its content view to `R.layout.layout_videos`.